# How can I implement excel sumif type function in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I add up different values in a column based on a certain set of criteria in another column?
Same as that can be done on excel using Sumif

Comment: `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN somecondition THEN somevalue WHEN ..... END)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Select SalesAgent
      ,JanSales = sum(case when SalesMonth=1 then Sales else 0 end)
      ,FebSales = sum(case when SalesMonth=2 then Sales else 0 end)
      ... {march - november}
      ,DecSales = sum(case when SalesMonth=12 then Sales else 0 end)
      ,Total    = sum(Sales)
 From SalesData
 Group By SalesAgent
 Order By SalesAgent
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum all values of a column for rows that match a certain criteria:

```
SELECT Sum(value1) FROM Table WHERE value2=something
```

Comment: Thats ok when the where clause has static reference, and a small set of criteria. How can I do it when I have a huge list for the where clause to go through, like everything on one of the columns?